# how to display "file types included" in zip files for simple / downloadable products on woocommecre

Tags: php, file, woocommerce

I have added the code below to my WooCommerce site to display the file format of a downloadable asset.

to be displayed on a single product page

For ZIP files, I would like the display to indicate the files which are contained within the compressed archive, so the shoppers of simple/downloadable products know the formats of the product data which they will receive. How can this be achieved please?

[image]

````php
global $product;
$downloads = $product->get_files();
foreach( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {
  $info     = pathinfo($each_download["file"]);
  $ext      = $info['extension'];
  $formats .= $ext . ", ";
}
echo '<p> File Format: '. $formats .'</p>';
?>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Hello like @user6316291 said, zipArchive works.
Since it's in WooCommerce, you can try this code.

```
<?php
/*
 * This block should be in the proper place of mytheme/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php file.
 * Hope this helps you, but still, enjoy at your own risk. :)
 */

/**
 * Single Product Meta
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
global $product;
?>
<div class="product_meta">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>
    <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>
        <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
    <?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>


    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>

<?php
// ########################################

/**
 * Display files in zip file.
 *
 * @author Precious Omonzejele (CodeXplorer)
 * @param string $zip_full_path The absolute url path.
 * @param string $display (optional) any valid key of pathinfo(), default is extension.
 * @param bool   $avoid_duplicate (optional) set true if you don't want duplicate list, default is false.
 * @return mixed false if zip file couldn't be opened, string otherwise
 */
function pekky_break_down_zip( $zip_full_path, $display, $avoid_duplicate = false ) {
    // Divide file path.
    $path = explode( '/uploads/', $zip_full_path );
    if ( empty( $path ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $file_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/' . $path[1];

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    $res  = $zip->open( $file_path );
    $data = '';
    // To detect if a file has been listed, to avoid repetition.
    $data_store = array();
    if ( true === $res ) {
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ ) {

            $info        = pathinfo( $zip->getNameIndex( $i ) );
            $single_info = $info[ $display ];

            // Does something exist and if avoid_duplicate is set, is it already listed?
            if ( $single_info ) {
                if ( $avoid_duplicate && in_array( $single_info, $data_store, true ) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                $data_store[] = $single_info;
                $data        .= $single_info . ( ( $zip->numFiles - $i ) == 1 ? '' : ', ' );
            }
        }
        $zip->close(); // Always close this .
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
    // End of Custom Function.

    $downloads   = $product->get_downloads();
    $part_needed = 'extension';
    $formats     = '';
foreach ( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {
    $file_path = $each_download['file'];
    $info      = pathinfo( $file_path );
    $f_data    = $info[ $part_needed ];

    echo '<br><br>';
    // Is it a zip file?
    if ( 'zip' === $f_data ) {
        $_format  = pekky_break_down_zip( $file_path, $part_needed, false );
        $formats .= ( ! empty( $_format ) ? $_format : '' );
    } else {
        $formats .= ( ! empty( $f_data ) ? $f_data . ', ' : '' );
    }
}
// Translators: %s is the format data.
$format_text = sprintf( __( 'file Format: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $formats );
echo ( ! empty( $formats ) ? '<p>' . esc_attr( $format_text ) . '</p>' : '' );
?>
</div>
```

you can find the gist here: https://gist.github.com/Preciousomonze/88e30062982a20b2f9af98e834964969

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ZipArchive to gather the index of the files within the zip.

Ensure that you have the module installed as detailed here https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

```
public function buildZipBreakdown(string $zipFile): array
{
    $result = [];
    if (file_exists($zipFile)) {
        $result = pathinfo($zipFile);
        if ($result['extension'] == "zip") {
            $za = new \ZipArchive();
            $za->open($zipFile);
            $result['num_files']  = $za->numFiles;
            if ($za->numFiles>0) {
                $result['files'] = [];
                for ($i=0; $i<$za->numFiles; $i++) {
                    $file_object = $za->statIndex($i);
                    $result['files'][] = [
                        "filename" => $file_object['name'],
                        "size" => $file_object['size'],
                        "date" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $file_object['mtime'])
                    ];
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("EMPTY_INVALID_ZIP");
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("NOT_ZIP_EXT");
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("NOT_FOUND");
    }
    return  $result;
}
```

You can tailor it to your needs.

Comment: Hi
thanks for your answer, because I am a beginner to the code section
so where do I add the code you provide
is it in mytheme / woocommerce / templates / single-product / meta.php
or on theme function.php

Comment: I don't know, I can't advice you on code placement in the Framework you've chosen, your question was specifically about how to list the contents of a ZIP file.

Comment: Hi
please see my re-edited question
and screenshots
Thank you very much

Comment: See https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/ -